# Regex to check a substring is having all numeric or not (in Java script)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using following code to check first four characters are alphabate or not.

```
var pattern = new RegExp('^[A-Z]{4}');
if (enteredID.match(pattern))
    isValidAlphabates = true;
else {
    isValidAlphabates = false;
```

This is working fine; Now I need to check the next 6 characters (of the entered text) need to be only numeric (0 to 9).

I ve the option to use substring or substr method to extract that part & use the regular experssion: ^[0-9]{6}.

But is there a better way to do it, without using the substring method here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, the ^ means "at the start of the string". So you can combine your two regexes to say "start with four A-Z then have six 6 0-9."

```
var pattern = new RegExp('^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{6}');
```

Answer (score 1):

var pattern = `new RegExp('^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{6}');`

Answer (score 1):

```
var pattern = new RegExp('^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{6}$');
```

I added `$` that means that checked string must end there.

Comment: Can u please let me know wats might go wrong if we wont use $, as I am not able to find any difference in my dev testing.

Comment: Without `$` it will match `ABCD123456abcdef`. You can test regexp (Python flavor, but in this simple example it does not matter) on: http://pythonregex.appspot.com/.

Comment: Ok, Then I think $ is not required for my regex. As my input has some more characters left after the above validation done.          Wat is the significance of using +$, instead of only $?

Comment: '+' can be added to previous character/string to show that is there should be at least one such character/string. Look at JavaScript RegExp description: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can check the whole string at once

```
var pattern = new RegExp('^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{6}');
```